# Why does CALayer backing stores is not in heap?

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer

In WWDC 2012 Session 242, Apple says 'CALayer backing stores' is not stores in heap,that's why,and what does 'CALayer backing stores'?[image]

Answer (score 0):

i think, this little tutor will help you https://gist.github.com/andrewsardone/3751168